# Bootstrap and ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I would like advice, I have to develop a project in ASP .NET, (I would like to use ASP MVC 5 but I'm just learning). I would like to do this project with ASP .NET and integrate it with bootstrap and jQuery for some queries to the server.

I know that this approach is not optimal, but I do not have much time to gain experience with MVC. My questions are (assuming I use ASP .NET):

1) The integration (with bootstrap) is complicated?

2) It is more convenient to use ASP controls such as:

```
<asp: textbox id = "SingleText" text = "Single Line TextBox" runat = "server" />
```

or directly HTML code?

3) Can I have problems in the future due to using this technology?

Really thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what ASP.NET is. ASP.NET includes Web Forms (which you seem to think is what ASP.NET is) and MVC, and several other technologies like Razor Pages, SignalR etc. You're using Web Forms, which is a very old (and hated) technology. If you want to learn something easier and more relevant to actual jobs out there today, then MVC would be a far better choice.

Answer (score 0):

**1) The integration (with bootstrap) is complicated?**

it is very easy task, and there are ready templates with a build-in bootstrap

---

**2) It is more convenient to use ASP controls such as:**

```
<asp: textbox id = "SingleText" text = "Single Line TextBox" runat = "server" />
```

**or directly HTML code?**

you can use both html helper or , such as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.name)
```

or use html tags directly, such as:

```
<label for="name"></label>
```

---

**3) Can I have problems in the future due to using this technology?**

no, it is modern and stable technology